# mp3 audio playback not working with Cordova 3.5 on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, cordova

Recently I upgraded our iOS Project from Cordova 3.3 to 3.5.

mp3 files (that were previously downloaded into the iOS standard documents folder) will not play using the media API / plugin. This code has been working reliably on iOS for many versions up and including Cordova 3.3... The mp3 files have been downloaded into a subdirectory called 'Downloads' in the standard iOS App 'documents' folder..

In XCode console I get the following error:

Unknown resource 'file://localhost/Users/weeasle/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/{App-ID}/Documents/Downloads/testsound.mp3'

In my code (after a few blocks of code for the File Plugin API) I get the directory using:  downloadDirFullPath = window.appRootDir.toURL();

To comply with the new changes in 3.5's file API, I recently changed this from 
downloadDirFullPath = window.appRootDir.fullPath;

Is the Media Plugin API for Cordova 3.5 broken for audio playback from the iOS App Documents directory???

Or am I just really tired and missing something obvious... Any suggestions or info greatly appreciated.

Chris
aka weeasle

UPDATE ON 20/Jun/14: Fix Found. I can now get my downloaded .mp3's to play on iOS Cordova 3.5... Apparently with the new Cordova 3.5 filesystem the entry.fullPath method no longer works and is replaced by entry.toURL() as per https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

This works fine when calling images with Cordova, However there has been a quirk with the Media Plugin on iOS for quite some time:  For sound playback, it does not accept URLs starting with file:///    it only takes absolute paths like  /var/mobile/Applications/{GUID}/Documents/

The answer and fix is to use the new toInternalURL() method called within the entry returned from fileSystem.root.getDirectory. The exact call I use is downloadDirFullPath = window.appRootDir.toInternalURL(); (called from the entry passed by fileSystem.root.getDirectory).

This returns: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Downloads/  which when pre-pended to .mp3 or other audio files plays successfully in iOS..

This also works for displaying images and media so it is a single reliable solution for Cordova iOS 3.5 and up..

This is by far the preferred solution since it is safer than using relative paths (as if in future Apple makes significant file structure changes with an iOS release, file access could break)...

One further note - in addition to the calls/methods above, downloadDirName = window.appRootDir.name;  also sets cdvfile://localhost/persistent/  base path

Weeasle

Comment: Did you tried some relativ path like: < NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];`>

Comment: Thanks Watsche for your immediate response. I was just editing the question and saw your post... Unfortunately I am a complete novice with ObjC and rely on the Cordova/Phonegap API...  As mentioned in the edited answer I did try relative addressing - some older versions of Cordova mention relative addresses... But no joy...

Comment: Thanks. A lot of small things changes (sometimes just for the sake of it) and they are never documented.That is the thing I hate the most about Cordova/Phonegap

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played around with media on iOS recently but if I look at the docs it states:

```
var myMedia = new Media("audio/beer.mp3")
myMedia.play()  
// first looks for file in www/audio/beer.mp3 then in 
<application>/documents/tmp/audio/beer.mp3
```

So, if I were you I'd try a relative path of:

```
"../Downloads/testsound.mp3"
```

which should change:

```
<application>/documents/tmp/../Downloads/testsound.mp3
```

into just:

```
<application>/documents/Downloads/testsound.mp3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Simon - Much appreciate your guidance.. I was about to play around with relative paths more and then thankfully I found the fix - Please see the above question I have updated - I know you will want to pass this info along to Cordova Devs on iOS as it solves how to play audio with media plugin on iOS with the new Cordova 3.5 filesystem plugin changes..

Comment: any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455884/file-copyto-not-working-in-cordova

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me with latest cordova 3.5 version is there:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/06/23/Cordova-Media-API-Example

Make sure to install this plugin:
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git

Answer (score 0):

The prefix **documents** ended working for me to take me to a persistent storage location within the app. In the source for the iOS plug-in it looks like you can use these prefixes:

```
"documents://"
"http://"
"https://"
"cdvfile://"
```