# Cordova 3.5: Media Playback Issue

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, media, hybrid

I recently updated my hybrid app to Cordova 3.5 and it seems as if there is an issue with media playback. I have this simple. (url is declared before).

```
var my_media = new Media(url,
    // success callback
    function() {
        //alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
    // error callback
    function(err) {
        alert("playAudio():Audio Error: "+JSON.stringify(err));
});

my_media.play();
```

I have tried this with both relative and absolute URI's however; none play any sound.

I believe [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205331/mp3-audio-playback-not-working-with-cordova-3-5-on-ios) had the same issue. I am not using Xcode so I don't understand most of this.

Any info would be helpful,

Thanks.

Comment: What are you passing for the url/uri argument?

Comment: @johnhight I have tried both relative (sounds/sound.mp3) and absolute (file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/(many numbers...)/Library/Caches/Projects/(more numbers...)/www/sounds/sound.mp3) uris; however, none work.